# Date vs Timestamp for Firebase

Tags: date, datetime, timestamp, firebase

What would you recommend to store dates using [Firebase](http://firebase.com) between a datetime and a timestamp, and why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a timestamp as this is locale-agnostic and does not require formatting and parsing agreements between clients. It's also a bit shorter.

Furthermore, utilize [Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/servervalue/TIMESTAMP.html), rather than trusting the clients to have their clocks set correctly. If, for example, a client's clock is off by 5 minutes and you utilize the client timestamps in a chat conversation, then rendering back the messages, the time shown would appear to be 5 minutes in the future for other users.

Comment: Thanks @Kato, spot on. I was actually getting the date from users using new Date(); and saving it to firebase which resulted in posts appearing to be from the future.

Comment: New docs here for TIMESTAMP: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Kato re: " Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP". If i'm using the REST API directly, how would I generate the timestamp?